# Linear regression with gradient descent to predict house prices using area (one var) in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

Im trying to train a model using linear regression and gradient descent to predict the house prices based on area in sq ft but idk whats wrong, the predicted hx (hypothesis) is larger than values. havent coded the for the prediction as i am getting error. help me out. ty

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

db = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
x = np.array(db.iloc[:40,5])
y = np.array(db.iloc[:40,11])
m = len(x)
t0=0
t1=1
alpha = 0.001
for i in range(m):
    hx = t0 + t1*x
    dt0 = (-2/m)*sum((hx - y))
    dt1 = (-2/m)*sum(x*(hx - y))
    t0 = t0 - dt0*alpha
    t1 = t1 - dt1*alpha
print(t0,t1)
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x,hx)
```

also dataset,

x = [1300.236407 , 1275.       ,  933.1597222,  929.9211427,
999.009247 , 1250.       , 1495.053957 , 1181.012946 ,
1040.       ,  879.1208791, 1350.308642 , 1333.010179 ,
927.1779023, 1122.171946 ,  649.9837504, 1394.117647 ,
1800.08471  , 2124.896706 , 1100.       , 2178.649237 ,
881.1435285,  944.8818898, 1310.147689 ,  630.00063  ,
1219.80971  ,  780.141844 , 1600.       , 1180.412371 ,
1000.       , 1000.       , 1400.107701 ,  943.1266076,
1150.146382 ,  864.0674394,  857.7861968, 1174.210077 ,
1020.087884 , 1650.165017 , 1000.       , 1300.052002 ]

y = [ 55. ,  51. ,  43. ,  62.5,  60.5,  42. ,  66.5,  52. ,  41.6,
36. ,  35. , 110. ,  48. ,  62. ,  20. ,  71.1,  85. , 180. ,
22. , 120. ,  45. ,  42. ,  55. , 300. ,  50. ,  27.5,  46. ,
22.9,  39. ,  12.5,  52. ,  33. ,  55. ,  82. , 240. ,  55. ,
65. ,  65. ,  35. ,  75. ]

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you need gradient descent for this in the first place and why you need to write an algorithm for that from scratch apart from educational purposes. I would recommend to use established packages for that like [Sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) or [Statsmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/regression.html).

Otherwise linear regression can be solved directly like [this](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/regression-analysis/find-a-linear-regression-equation/#FindaLinear), or, if you want to use logistic (again a kind of linear regression) the above packages allow you to select what solver to use (I am not sure whether gradient descent is one of them as there are more controllable ways to solve linear problems that that).

Good luck!